# Calculating loss from action and reward in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to calculate loss in an RL project with 3 discrete actions. I have the output prediction of my model for (from `tf.layers.dense()`) (e.g. 3 possible actions, batch size 2):

```
[[10, 20.2, 4.3],
 [5, 3, 8.9]]
```

I have a the action that was taken by the agent (e.g.):

```
[[1],
 [2]]
```

And I have the reward for taking that action from the environment (e.g):

```
[[30.0],
 [15.0]]
```

I want to calculate the loss for the taken action, using the action as an index and the reward. I don't have any information for the actions that weren't taken. If it were just calculating the difference I'd expect the loss (from the previous examples) to be:

```
[[0, 9.8, 0],
 [0, 0, 6.1]]
```

I've tried:

```
updated = tf.scatter_update(logits, action, reward)
loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=updated, logits=logits)
```

But this gives `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_lazy_read'`. I believe this is because the inputs are Tensors but not Variables which `scatter_update()` requires.

How can I calculate loss for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `scatter_update` because that's for 1D data. You probably need to take a look at how [gather_nd](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) and [scatter_nd](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd) works. But the following code works for your problem.

```
import tensorflow as tf

num_actions = 3
batch_size = 2
tf.reset_default_graph()

output = tf.convert_to_tensor([[10, 20.2, 4.3],[5, 3, 8.9]])

# There's a bit of dark magic looking reshaping going here
# Essentially to get tensor a in the correct shape of indices
# gather_nd requires
a_idx = tf.reshape(tf.range(batch_size),[-1,1])

a = tf.convert_to_tensor([[1],[2]])

a_reshaped = tf.reshape(tf.concat([a_idx,a],axis=1),[-1,1,2])

r = tf.convert_to_tensor([[30.0],[15.0]])

diff = tf.gather_nd(output, a_reshaped)
loss = tf.scatter_nd(a_reshaped, r-diff, (batch_size, num_actions))
```

Comment: Seems correct for this example but didn't generalise to other batch sizes. I've edited it so that it would.